# Cache, Branch predictor and TLB maintenance operations

Tags: caching, assembly, arm, cpu-cache, memory-barriers

About ARM `DSB` memory barrier [instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHGHHIE.html):

> DSB -
>
> Data Synchronization Barrier acts as a special kind of memory
>   barrier. No instruction in program order after this instruction
>   executes until this instruction completes.

Well understood, Next:

> This instruction completes
>   when:
>
> All explicit memory accesses before this instruction complete.
>
> All Cache, Branch predictor and TLB **maintenance** operations before this
>   instruction complete.

Wait, what exactly is cache, branch predictor and TLB **maintenance** means? Does it means flushing? and does it means that the `DSB` instruction itself can trigger such flushing? and what else is considered as maintenance?

Comment: I think they mean all cache side-effects of normal load/store instructions complete before anything after the DSB, as well as effects of any explicit TLB-invalidate instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes what about branch predictor maintenance?

Comment: If you specifically do a `mcr cp15...` where you are doing CP15 operations on cache, predictor or TLB, then those operations will complete.  Often several instruction may gang and then a `DSB` issued depending on the use case.  For instance, you may invalidate the cache and TLB when updating MMU tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue of English grammar ambiguity.  I think they mean

- cache operation (all side-effects of loads/stores, or explicit flush / invalidate after an MMU operation)
- branch predictor operation (e.g. globally enable/disable branch prediction)
- TLB-maintenance operation (e.g. invalidate a TLB entry after changing a page table entry)

I don't think they're trying to describe branch-predictor operations as "maintenance", and the word "maintenance" is only supposed to go with "TLB" in that sentence.

(Some branch-predictor operations could maybe be described as maintenance, if ARM has added branch-predictor flush operations for Spectre mitigation, the way Intel has for their x86 CPUs with their recent microcode updates that added a new model-specific register.  (https://access.redhat.com/articles/3311301).  But I don't think that's what their sentence is trying to say here.)

Comment: There are branch predictor operations for some ARM CPU models (before spectre).  They are highly model dependant.  Some only allow enable/disable of the predictor (which would be an operation of sorts).

Comment: @artlessnoise: Thanks.  updated.  So that would be a branch predictor operation, but not "maintenance".

Answer (score 1):

The key point to disambiguating this is to recognise that `TLB maintenance` is a significantly more common term than `TLB operation`. (by a factor of about 3 according to a simple search).

Where `TLB operation` is used alone, it seems to refer to either the process of operation, or to a specific identified activity. Where instructions are described as interacting with the TLB, these are described under the heading of `TLB maintenance operations` and this group forms a fairly large set. This set of instructions will generally not be described as just `TLB operations`, so your proposed parsing requires splitting a common (if not explicitly standard) term in the documentation.